# Search on a specific page for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, searchbar

Right now the search bar only searches for posts and such.
I have created a plugin and a subtheme/page for my site which displays data from this plugin. Basically it's persons and I want to be able to search for them both with name and description.

I have no idea where to start, can I change the current search bar's algorithm or do I have to change it completely?

I saw some plugins but I am unsure which one to choose, the easiest would be to make the entire site searchable but I guess that could make the results a bit too much as well I think.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the original question.

Comment: well I was thinking more if there is some plugin that does this.

Comment: There might be.  However, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." At that point, you need to do the proper research and see if you can find any plugin that does what you want. If you can't find any, you'll need to build your own.